# How to change icon using delegate in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, delegates

I am using a delegate in a Qtreeview which just shows an icon next to the text.

What I would like to be able to do is click on one of the items from the list and change the icon of just that one item. I have been looking through some examples but they all use editors which I don't want to do. I want the change to happen automatically on the click action of an item.

I am geussing that I will have to add a new function to my delegate class with the index of the item that i have clicked which is fine, but how do I change the icon ? Do I have to recall the paint function with a new icon to paint ?

This is the delegate that i'm using :

```
void SeqNavDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
       const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);

    if (index.column() == 0 && option.state & QStyle::State_Enabled)//State_MouseOver)
    {
        const QIcon icon(QLatin1String(":/SeqNavMenu/images/grey.png"));

        QRect iconRect(option.rect.right() - option.rect.height(),
                       option.rect.top(),
                       option.rect.height(),
                       option.rect.height());

        icon.paint(painter, iconRect, Qt::AlignRight);
    }
}
```

Do i just reimplement this function with a different icon path ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it is very straightforward by re-implemanting initStyleOption() in derivative of QStyledItemDelegate. I needed my items, representing folders, to change icon from closed to open in response to user action:

```
class MyDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    MyDelegate(QObject *parent = 0)
        : QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
    {
    }
protected:
    virtual void initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem * option, const QModelIndex & index) const
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(option, index);
        if (QStyleOptionViewItemV4 *v4 = qstyleoption_cast<QStyleOptionViewItemV4 *>(option))
        {
            const MyModel *model(static_cast<const MyModel *>(index.model()));
            if ((option->state & QStyle::State_Open) && model->isFolderItem(index))
                v4->icon = QIcon(toFolderIconStr(true));
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

**Process a click**

Let's start with user click on a row. Subscribe to a signal `clicked (const QModelIndex&)` of `QAbstractItemView`.

According to a concept of `Model/View` View displays data which a model provides.  To display a text you have already reimplemented method `data` in your model and the model started providing a text. Now you want to display icons. Until it was needed to display only one icon you could do it from a delegate. Now you need to make your model provide needed icon or a state based on which an icon can be selected.
To provide an icon the model should know which icon should be shown for each row. Create a variable to keep clicked state for each row.

In a slot connected to `clicked` signal notify the model that clicked state of a row has changed:

```
 {
   bool oldState = m_model->data(index, Qt::UserRole).toBool();
   m_model->setData(index, !oldState, Qt::UserRole);
 }
```

**Add processing of `Qt:UserRole` to `setData`:**

```
{
  if (role == Qt:UserRole)
    setClickedState(index, value.toBool());
}
```

Don't forget to notify the view that your data in this row has changed. At the end of `setData` call `emit dataChanged(index, index)`. And this is the answer to your question how to make the view to repaint. It will be repained as soon as it recieves you signal.

**Add processing of `Qt:UserRole` to `data`:**

```
if (role == Qt::UserRole)
   return clickedState(index);
```

**Ask for the clicked state from the delegate and draw needed icon**

```
const QAbstractItemModel* model = index.model();
const bool state = model->data(index, Qt::UserRole).toBool();
const QIcon& iconToBeDrawn = state ? checkedIcon : icon;
```

**P.S.**
You use a custom delegate for wrong purpose. A custom delegate is needed when you need to paint something which cannot be painted with a standard `QStyledItemDelegate`. But it can draw icons.
To draw an icon you need to process `Qt::DecorationRole` in your model like this:

```
virtual QVariant data (const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
  ...
  if (role == Qt::DecorationRole)
        return someIcon;
  ...
}
```

`QStyledItemDelegate` draws an icons in the left by default. Here in my comment I suggested to you how to make it paint it in the right side of a row:
[Delegate erasing text in QTreeView using QStandardItemModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426793/delegate-erasing-text-in-qtreeview-using-qstandarditemmodel/25427425#comment39668040_25427425)

The same way you provide a text for each row you can provide an icon:

```
if (role == Qt::DecorationRole)
   return ifClicked(index) ? someIcon : otherIcon;
```